# C# List OrderBy creates an OutOfMemory Error

Tags: c#, list, sql-order-by

I tried to Sort an List by an property which i get dynamiclly.
When i run my code with Strength on first position and Range on second i get an OutOfMemory Error, but when i change the order everything works fine.

Code:

```
public enum EffectType
{
    Duration,
    Efficiency,
    Range,
    Strength
}

public List<Modlist> Sort(List<EffectType> filter) {
    return ComboList.OrderByDescending(
        x => x.GetType()
            .GetProperty(filter[0].ToString())
            .GetValue(x, null))
    .ThenByDescending(
        y => y.GetType()
            .GetProperty(filter[1].ToString())
            .GetValue(y, null))
    .ToList();
}

public class Modlist
{
    public List<Mod> Mods { get; set; }
    public float Strength { get; set; }
    public float Range { get; set; }
    public float Duration { get; set; }
    public float Efficiency { get; set; }
}
```

I can't find the error and searched for days now.

Comment: Are you sure you have a `ToList` between your `OrderByDescending` and `ThenByDescending`?  Beacause I don't think that would compile.

Comment: sorry forgot to edit it

Comment: I'd suggest avoiding reflection if you can.  It looks like you'd have to add a new enum value everytime you add a property anyway so you might as well write the code to map the enums to the properties like `if(filter[0] == EffectType.Strenth) result = ComboList.OrderByDescending(x => x.Strength);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reflection is slow, so try avoid it if it's possible.
You can achieve the same effect with value selectors like this:

```
return ComboList
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Duration)
    .ToList();
```

In your case you may create a dictionary of selectors like this:

```
private readonly Dictionary<EffectType, Func<Modlist, float>> selectors
    = new Dictionary<EffectType, Func<Modlist, float>>
{
  { EffectType.Duration, m => m.Duration },
  { EffectType.Efficiency, m => m.Efficiency },
  { EffectType.Range, m => m.Range },
  { EffectType.Strength, m => m.Strength }
};
```

And then convert your enum items into selectors and use them:

```
public List<Modlist> Sort(List<EffectType> filters)
{
    if (filters.Count < 1) // no sort is required
        return ComboList;

    var currentSelectors = filters
        .Select(f => selectors[f])
        .ToArray();

    var sorted = ComboList.OrderByDescending(currentSelectors[0]);
    for (var i = 1; i < currentSelectors.Length; ++i)
        sorted = sorted.ThenByDescending(currentSelectors[i]);

    return sorted.ToList();
}
```

Comment: This solution ist great! Thanks.
But my problem remains. I still get an OutOfMemory exception

Comment: @MaddEye are you sure you get an exception in `Sort` method? And what is `ComboList`? Is it a regular `List<Modlist>` or it is a `IQueryable<Modlist>`?

Comment: Yes i'm sure
when i command the line out everthing works fine. And its an rugalar List<Modlist>